# how to fix make_response error by adding mimetype to json data ty pe in Flask

Tags: flask

I am trying to make slurm-web code working.
in restapi.py, there is a def sinfo() method which reads as follows:

```
@app.route('/sinfo', methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS'])
@crossdomain(origin=origins, methods=['GET'],
             headers=['Accept', 'Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With', 'Authorization'])
@authentication_verify()
def sinfo():

    # Partition and node lists are required
    # to compute sinfo informations
    partitions = get_from_cache(pyslurm.partition().get, 'get_partitions')
    nodes = get_from_cache(pyslurm.node().get, 'get_nodes')

    # Retreiving the state of each nodes
    nodes_state = dict(
        (node.lower(), attributes['state'].lower())
        for node, attributes in nodes.iteritems()
    )

    # For all partitions, retrieving the states of each nodes
    sinfo_data = {}
    for name, attr in partitions.iteritems():

        for node in list(NodeSet(attr['nodes'])):
            key = (name, nodes_state[node])
            if key not in sinfo_data.keys():
                sinfo_data[key] = []
            sinfo_data[key].append(node)

    # Preparing the response
    resp = []
    for k, nodes in sinfo_data.iteritems():
        name, state = k
        partition = partitions[name]
        avail = partition['state'].lower()
        min_nodes = partition['min_nodes']
        max_nodes = partition['max_nodes']
        total_nodes = partition['total_nodes']
        job_size = "{0}-{1}".format(min_nodes, max_nodes)
        job_size = job_size.replace('UNLIMITED', 'infinite')
        time_limit = partition['max_time_str'].replace('UNLIMITED', 'infinite')

        # Creating the nodeset
        nodeset = NodeSet()
        map(nodeset.update, nodes)

        resp.append({
          'name': name,
          'avail': avail,
          'job_size': job_size,
          'time_limit': time_limit,
          'nodes': total_nodes,
          'state': state,
          'nodelist': str(nodeset),
        })

    # Jsonify can not works on list, thus using json.dumps
    # And making sure headers are properly set
    return make_response(json.dumps(resp), mimetype='application/json')
```

apache error log says that 
  return make_response(json.dumps(resp), mimetype='application/json')
  TypeError: make_response() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'

I am using flase 1.0.2 and wondering what makes this error.

Comment: Make it a 3-step operation: `resp = make_response(json.dumps(resp)); resp.mimetype = 'application/json'; return resp`

Comment: @Abdou I followed your comment and got the following errors: TypeError: is not JSON serializable. If you please, can you explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to indent that `return` so that it happens at the end of `sinfo()`. Then you can simplify by writing

```
from flask import jsonify
...
def sinfo():
    ...
    return jsonify(resp)
```